# tomcat timeout configuration using AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat, configuration, timeout

session-timeout setting in web.xml is properly set, and tomcat is timing out at the specified value.  The problem is how the timeout is occurring.

Timeout is reset when navigating to a new page, however activating the browser (via keystore or mouse click), or making an AJAX call is not resetting the timeout.  I attempted a few tomcat properties to no avail, is there a property that handles this type of timeout configuration?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HttpSession is a server-side object, so key strokes and mouse events in the Web browser will not reset the timeout automatically. You could however monitor keyboard and mouse events on the client and make an RPC call to the server at regular intervals to keep your session alive.

But you're also saying that the Ajax calls don't reset the session timeout on the server. That's strange because I've done that many times and it does reset it for me. Are you using GWT RPC or another serialization mechanism ?

I'm not sure about that, but maybe you also need to *access* the session from the Ajax call implementation for the timeout to get reset, for example by calling `getThreadLocalRequest().getSession()` (if using GWT RPC).

Comment: As you mentioned, I need to access the session first, and find a way to reset the lastAccessTime for HttpSession (HttpServletSession in org.apache.shiro.web.session is out of scope, it's touch() method would have solved my issue).  I figured a tomcat property would be too good to be true :).  Should be able to find a solution from here, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete the connectionTimeout parameter in the server.xml file?

i.e: if you had this:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"  connectionTimeout="20000" URIEncoding="UTF-8"            redirectPort="8443" />
```

change it to:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"  connectionTimeout="<A VERY LARGE NUMBER>" URIEncoding="UTF-8"            redirectPort="8443" />
```

or:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8"            redirectPort="8443" />
```

Have you tried something like this, in your server.xml file?

Comment: The question is not about connection timeouts. It is about session timeouts. Not an answer.